# Solr ShingleFilterFactory in query analysis not worikng

Tags: solr4

I have field with definition below, I works perfect in analysis but when I try to query it in that way, query analysis behaves different. What I am missing?

**data:** thd_keyphrase: Privately held companies based in California,Social media,Privately held companies

**query:** q=thd_keyphrase:find any social media

in analysis query is processed this way: *|find any|any social|social media*

and it matches Social media

output from debug query is sifferent:

```
"rawquerystring": "thd_keyphrase:find any social media",
"querystring": "thd_keyphrase:find any social media",
"parsedquery": "thd_keyphrase:find text:ani text:social text:media",
"parsedquery_toString": **"thd_keyphrase:find text:ani text:social text:media",**
```

or when I remove default field text : "msg": "no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param",

```
<fieldType name="keyphrase" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" termVectors="false" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*,\s*"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> 
      <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
             outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" tokenSeparator=" "/>
    <!-- <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory" words="keepwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>-->
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have spaces in the text string make sure to surround it with double quotes like so:

q=thd_keyphrase:"find any social media"

Also, do you mean to tokenize the field on comma?

Comment: I have tried this...it works well for "social media", for "find any social media" it produces only one token... but I want to tokenize whole query into these tokens |find any|any social|social media

Comment: Change your maxShingleSize in ShingleFilterFactory to 2.

Comment: Thas not the problem...there can be more larger phrases in data... like "Place in northern Europe" ... I want to be able to parse query like "What is the best place in northen Europe ?" ... very confusing is that in the analysis it is working fine, it creates shingles and the biggest matches the phrase... but when I try it as a query it tries to look in default field ... maybe I miss something in querying, but it just should not search in default filed when I explicitly say look in thd_keyphrase...am I right?

Comment: I think your question may be a little deeper than what you mentioned in your post here. I would suggest to examine edismax query parer and various query fields (qf), phrase (pf) and slope (ps) arguments you can pass it.

Comment: Change to edismax parser helps me.